# Overriding datatables.js search behavior

Tags: javascript, datatables

There are already several questions here on SO on this subject, however none is about my exact situation.

I have a datatable with 2 columns, one contains text input field and the other a select. The current behavior of datatables' search functionality is to search in the entire select HTML. The behvior I want is search only the chosen option.

I'm aware we can override/intercept the search/filter events, ie

```
$('#mapping-table_filter input', data_table.table().container())
    .off('.DT')
    .on('keyup.DT cut.DT paste.DT input.DT search.DT', function (e) {
       data_table.search(...).draw();
    });

// or 

data_table.on('search.dt', function () {

});
```

But this does not help since `.search` does not accept a callback.

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0oabx2mr/

If you search for any of "first", "second" or "third" both rows are still visible. I want to be able to search for "second" and "third" and only get the relevant row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slight architecture changes, your example may look like that:

```js
var srcData = [
  ['firstOption', 'secondOption', 'thirdOption'],
  ['firstOption', 'secondOption', 'thirdOption'],
  ['firstOption', 'secondOption', 'thirdOption'],
  ['firstOption', 'secondOption', 'thirdOption']
];

var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [{
    title: 'Options',
    render: (data, type, row) => '<select>'+row.reduce((options, option) => options += `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`,'')+'</select>'
  }]
});

var needle = null;
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
  (settings, row, index) => $(dataTable.cell(`:eq(${index})`,':eq(0)').node()).find('select').val().match(needle) || !needle
);

$('#search').on('keyup', event => {
  needle = $(event.target).val();
  dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="search"></input>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good job! I've been trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works as expected. Please see a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687586/odd-behavior-of-search-function-after-modifying-it